# in some web pages, footer is not displaying correctly in IE 9 browser

Tags: css

I have a problem in footer display `IE9`,in some of the pages are not correctly fixed footer. The footer part is overlapping middle of the pages. But it correctly works fine in other browsers.

I have used below code for the footer to display.

```
 .footer { 
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0; 
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        height:80px; 
        clear:both; /*padding-top: 250px;*/ 
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
```

Comment: this is not enough for make a inform suggestion, you should sent us maybe  print screen, more code, also are you using any reset CSS, so broad question that could be anything. Elaborate your question, provide more information and maybe somebody can help you, what about posting a link to your page?

Comment: please check I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

for making footer fixed I used

```
.bottom_bar_fixed
{

    z-index: 999 !important;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
}
```

And this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer"></div>
```